# PDO and query troubleshoot - basic

Tags: php, pdo

I am converting an old php 5.6 code to 7.2 and learning how to use PDO.
I have reached a point where I got stuck and would like to learn from the community.

I created a test file structure:

**db.php:**

```
<?php    
try {
    $conn = new PDO($initlocation, $username, $pwdata);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "worked"; // THIS WORKS ON THE SCREEN
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();   
}
?>
```

**test.php:**

```
<?php

include("db.php");

$user_query='SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`="user1.a@gmail.com"';

echo $user_query; // I GET THE QUERY PRINTED ON THE SCREEN
echo is_object($conn); // THIS IS 1 WHICH IS GOD
echo "<br>";
echo is_object($res); // THIS IS 1 WHICH IS ODD

try{
    $res = $conn->query($user_query);
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage(); // NOTHING 
}

echo "<br>";
echo is_object($res); // NOTHING

$data_exists = $res->fetch();         
if ($data_exists==1) echo "yes"; // NOTHING            
?>
```

I have left the testing method in the code as well and I am keen to find a better solution to find out why the query does not show anything.

The aim would be to find the email address in the DB and give me some feedback about it. Thank you in advance all the comments I will only learn form them.

Additional info:
When I run the SQL query in the DB directly it does give me the record that has the same email.

Comment: What is your current output? What specific error(s) are you encountering?

Comment: Currently I have nothing meanwhile if I run the SQL query in the DB directly I get the record as the email address does exist in the DB.

Comment: You have a bunch of `echo` statements.  If you're not getting any output there's either a problem with the web server or something else about how the code is being executed.

Comment: @cegfault thank you for your time I have added the outputs in the question. Thank you again.

Comment: You should be catching `PDOException`, not `Exception`

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and use prepared statements like protection from SQL injections.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?');
$stmt->execute([$email]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: I have tried and I had nothing on the screen. I am keen to lear how to troubleshoot what is not working OK, thank you for your input. I will add the security element bit as well.

Comment: Have you try to turn displaying errors on? ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Array to string conversion in ... on line 14 Array

Comment: That PHP Notice gives a clue where is the problem, please add the error to description, so it can help future readers.

Comment: This was the solution. It turned out that the outcome is an array and the if ==1 would not respond. The Print_r function showed that there is a feedback.

Comment: Error message is/was: Array to string conversion in /home/sites/public_html/test/test.php on line 23

Comment: Yes, it can return an array, but fetch can be used with different fetch styles. Like PDO::FETCH_OBJ It returns a row as an anonymous object with column names as properties;